# Implement a struct in WASM text format

Tags: c++, webassembly

Does WASM text format have structs?

```
(module
   (type (; can a type be a `struct` like in C or rust? ;) )
   (; rest of module ;)
)
```

I've compiled the following c++ to wasm using [this WasmExplorer tool](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/)

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
  int MyField;
  long MyOtherField;
};

MyStruct returnMyStruct(int myField){
  return MyStruct {
    MyField: myField,
    MyOtherField: myField * 2
  };
}
```

It outputs the following, but I'm having trouble understanding what the WASM is doing.

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "_Z14returnMyStructi" (func $_Z14returnMyStructi))
 (func $_Z14returnMyStructi (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)
  (i32.store
   (get_local $0)
   (get_local $1)
  )
  (i32.store offset=4
   (get_local $0)
   (i32.shl
    (get_local $1)
    (i32.const 1)
   )
  )
 )
)
```

The function generated does not have a return type, it uses `i32.store` and `i32.shl` along with an offset. Is it storing the struct in memory somewhere?

An explanation of how and why this works would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever dealt with assembly? My 2 cents are that you shouldn't care a whole lot about the WASM that's output. It was designed to never be directly written.

Comment: I want to write a compiler that directly writes WASM, for educational purposes. For that reason, I only care about the WASM, not the C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does WASM text format have structs?

It does not. Like with other low-level assembly languages, wasm only has a few integer data types, and views memory as a big block of bytes. This is a simplification, but when a high level language like C is compiled to assembly, struct variables are allocated a spot in memory, with each field laid out at a different address. When you write to a field, it:

1. Takes the address of the struct variable
2. Adds the offset of the field from the root of the struct
3. Writes to the resulting address

---

> The function generated does not have a return type, it uses i32.store and i32.shl along with an offset. Is it storing the struct in memory somewhere?

What you're observing is a C++ feature, [Return Value Optmization (RVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Compilers are required since C++11 to avoid making extra copies of a PR-value struct (e.g. a temporary expression) getting returned from a function. While the standard doesn't dictate *how* to do that, many compilers accomplish this by converting the return value to an output parameter, e.g. this:

```cpp
MyStruct myFunc(int);
MyStruct myStruct;
myStruct = myFunc(42);
```

gets converted to this:

```cpp
void myFunc(MyStruct&, int);
MyStruct myStruct;
myFunc(myStruct, 42);
```

Now look again at the function signature:

```
 (func $_Z14returnMyStructi (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)
```

There are two parameters:

- `$0` is the address of a MyStruct, where the return value will be written
- `$1` is `myField`.

So this instruction:

```
  (i32.store
   (get_local $0)
   (get_local $1)
  )
```

Writes `myField` to the output address. In this case, the `MyField` member of `MyStruct` sits at offset zero, and is getting written.

And this instruction:

```
  (i32.store offset=4
   (get_local $0)
   (i32.shl
    (get_local $1)
    (i32.const 1)
   )
  )
```

`i32.shl` shifts `myField` left by 1 bit, effectively multiplying it by two. The result is written to an address 4 bytes after the output address. Since `MyOtherField` is laid out 4 bytes from the root of `MyStruct`, this is writing to `MyOtherField`.